# simple form country select showing as html entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, country

At some point my form started showing html entities instead of html for the country select:

Haml:

```
= a.input :country
```

Html

```
  <div class="input country required"><label class="country required" for="user_account_address_attributes_country">Country <abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><select class="country required" id="user_account_address_attributes_country" name="user[account_address_attributes][country]"><option value=""></option>
                          &lt;option value=&quot;Afghanistan&quot;&gt;Afghanistan&lt;/option&gt;
                          &lt;option value=&quot;Aland Islands&quot;&gt;Aland Islands&lt;/option&gt;
                          &lt;option value=&quot;Albania&quot; selected=&quot;selected&quot;&gt;Albania&lt;/option&gt;
```

Comment: can you provide any more info than this? Is your code versioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use the country_select gem.